# Mac open grep file list

Tags: file, file-io, command-line, grep, pipe

I want to search for a string in files and pipe the resulting file list to OSX's "open" command, thus opening all files that contain said string for editing in their default editor (aka not vim).

For example, running:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -l "RANDOMSTRING"
```

might return:

```
./folder1/file1.txt
./folder1/file2.txt
./folder2/file3.txt
./file4.txt
```

however, simply piping this list to the open command fails:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -l "RANDOMSTRING" | open
```

I think it's because of the "newlines" or "carriage returns" because running:

```
open ./folder1/file1.txt ./folder1/file2.txt ./folder2/file3.txt ./file4.txt
```

works.

I'm just not sure how to remove the newline characters from the returned output and pipe it to the open command. I need  another command to pipe the output through that will format the file list properly to then pipe the list to the open command. Although the newline characters may not even be the problem.

P.S. - I **DON'T** want to create a temp file to do this. I am however open to creating a .zshrc or .bashrc function.

Comment: tried with `xargs open` in last pipe?

Comment: @abasu. That did it. You should submit an answer so I can mark it as correct. If you don't I will so others can see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -l "RANDOMSTRING" | xargs open`

Only keeping `open` did not work because  the command `open` was expecting the input to be proper format, not coming from a stdin pipe. `xargs` is there to read line by line from stdin and feed it to `open`. Also for a sidenote, `xargs` sometimes have problem with filename containing spaces. So with find, use `-print0` option at the end to deal with that. Sample find with xargs is available in `man xargs`